# How can I optimize this raw SQL and perhaps implement it via CodeIgniter?

Tags: mysql, optimization, codeigniter-2

It's been a while since I've written raw SQL, I was hoping someone could help me out in optimizing this SQL query so that it works across, both, MySQL and PostgreSQL.

I would also have to implement this via CodeIgniter (2.x) using ActiveRecord, any help/advice?

```
       SELECT *
     FROM notaries, contact_notaries
    WHERE notaries.id = contact_notaries.notary_id
AND WHERE (   contact_notaries.city LIKE %$criteria%
           OR contact_notaries.state LIKE %$criteria
           OR contact_notaries.address LIKE %$criteria%)
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

1. Each query can have just one `WHERE` clause (you don't need the second)
2. It's much better to put join condition into `JOIN` rather then `WHERE`.
3. Are you sure you really need all the columns from 2 tables (`*`)?
   So I'd refactor it to

`SELECT [field_list]

 FROM notaries

 INNER JOIN contact_notaries ON (notaries.id = contact_notaries.notary_id)

 WHERE ( contact_notaries.city LIKE '%$criteria%'

       OR contact_notaries.state LIKE '%$criteria'

       OR contact_notaries.address LIKE '%$criteria%')`

Answer (score 0):

Using a1ex07's query:

```
SELECT [field_list]
FROM notaries
INNER JOIN contact_notaries ON (notaries.id = contact_notaries.notary_id)
WHERE ( contact_notaries.city LIKE '%$criteria%'
OR contact_notaries.state LIKE '%$criteria'
OR contact_notaries.address LIKE '%$criteria%')
```

Active record:

```
$this->db->select(); // Leave empty to select all fields
$this->db->join('contact_notaries', 'notaries.id = contact_notaries.notary_id', 'inner');
$this->db->like('contact_notaries.city', 'criteria');
$this->db->like('contact_notaries.state', 'criteria');
$this->db->like('contact_notaries.address', 'match');
$results = $this->db->get('notaries');
```

To specify a list of fields you can do `$this->db->select('field_1, field_2, ...');`.

http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/active_record.html